# Is there an R function to include mixed colours in one subject (column, line, map...)

Tags: r, plot, colors

I want to use multiple colours to express information on a map. For example, for a region, the value of variable A is a, the variable of variable B is b. I set red to A, and blue to B. Since I want to show a and b simultaneously, I hope the colour of this region is purple. If the purple has more red, it indicates a is bigger, and vice versa. The darker the purple, the bigger the value of a+b. This idea is like a thermodynamic diagram.

Really thanks if you can provide any clues!

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. Please include a sample of your data and the code you have tried to make your question reproducible. Have you had a chance to look at the guidance about how to ask a really good question [ask] and how to make a reprodicible example[reprex]?

Comment: It'd be great to see the code you've got so far, but there are potentially a couple of ways to go with this: 1) specifying colours with the function `rgb()` given arguments for `red` and `blue` from your data; 2) plotting the blue areas first, then overlaying the red using a transparency value (alpha) of say 0.5 so you can see some of the blue behind

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I feel my idea is not that abstract now. I am so sorry that I am working on a proposal and I have not cleaned out data yet, but I want to check for the feasibility of this idea. :)